# Continuity of the real and imaginary parts of a continuus complex-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis

If a complex-valued function is continuous, are the component real and imaginary parts $u(x,y)$ and $u(x,y)$ necessarily continuous? If so, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions $\operatorname{Re}, \operatorname{Im}: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous since $\operatorname{Re} (z_1+z_2) = \operatorname{Re} z_1 + \operatorname{Re} z_2$ and $|\operatorname{Re} z | \le |z|$, and similarly for $\operatorname{Im}$.

Hence $\operatorname{Re} \circ f$ and $\operatorname{Im} \circ f$ are continuous.

Answer (score 5):

A complex valued function $f = u + iv$ is continuous if and only if $u$ and $v$ are continuous, since $|u(z)-u(z')| \le |f(z)-f(z')| \le |u(z)-u(z')| + |v(z)-v(z')|$.

Answer (score 2):

Projections from any topological product space are continuous by the definition of a product space. Since $\mathbb C$ is topologically the same as $\mathbb R^2$, $\operatorname{Re}$ and $\operatorname{Im}$ are continuous. But the situation is entirely general—it applies also to such crazy things as $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$.

Applying composition as in copper.hat's answer answers your question.